# CUDATranspose bad result

Tags: warning-messages, cudalink, gpu

A fairly simple experiment, I am trasponsing an identitiy (3x3) matrix, and I got a weird result. I tried also CUDADot and works as expected.

The code I used:

```
a = CUDAMemoryLoad[{{1,0,0},{0, 1, 0},{0,0,1}}]

g=CUDAMemoryLoad[{{1,1,0},{0,1,1},{1,0,1}}]

b=CUDADot[a,g];

c=CUDATranspose[a];

CUDAMemoryGet[a]//MatrixForm
```

> (1.    0.  0., 0.  1.  0., 0.  0.  1.)

```
CUDAMemoryGet[b]//MatrixForm
```

> (1.    1.  0., 0.  1.  1., 1.  0.  1.)

```
CUDAMemoryGet[c]//MatrixForm
```

> (6.94986*10^-310   0.  6.64419*10^-316,
>   2.*10^-323  6.9499*10^-310  6.9499*10^-310,
>   6.9499*10^-310  6.94986*10^-310 6.94989*10^-310)

The system has 3 GPU's, 2 GTX Titan and 1 GeForce GT 630. In the same machine with matlab all is working correctly (so, it seems to be Mathematica specific error):

> > X = eye(3);
> >     G = gpuArray(X);
> >     G'

ans =

```
 1     0     0
 0     1     0
 0     0     1
```

Any feedback is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: After several tries I have found that with Mathematica 10.4 and nvidia drivers 367.27 and upgrading to the latest CUDAResources paclet everythig is working ok

Comment: You could put that as an answer, if you like.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of an answer:

> After several tries I have found that with Mathematica 10.4 and nvidia drivers 367.27 and upgrading to the latest CUDAResources paclet everythig is working ok – Javier Vales Alonso 2 days ago